# Best way to write unit tests for dictionary

Tags: actionscript-3, unit-testing, dictionary, hashmap

This is kinda related to my other question: [flex dictionary bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8929128/612920)

The HashMap has a method getValues() which returns an array of values:

```
protected var map:Dictionary = null;
public function HashMap(useWeakReferences:Boolean = true)
{
    map = new Dictionary( useWeakReferences );
}

public function getValues() : Array
{
    var values:Array = [];

    for (var key:* in map)
    {
        values.push( map[key] );
    }
    return values;
}
```

In my unit test class, I have:

```
private var map:IMap;

[Before]
public function setUp():void
{
    map = new HashMap();
    map.put("a", "value A");
    map.put("b", "value B");
    map.put("c", "value C");
    map.put("x", "value X");
    map.put("y", "value Y");
    map.put("z", "value Z");
}
[Test]
public function testGetValues():void
{
    assertEquals(map.getValues(), /*what should I put here*/);
}
```

the loop `for (var key:* in map)` iterates the keys of the dictionary `map`, but it seems its implementation does it in some random way. What is the best way to write a test since I don't know what the array returned by getValues method will contain?
I thought I could do it by calling the sort method, and compare the values, is there a better way to do it?

```
assertEquals(map.getValues().sort(), "value A,value B,value C,value X,value Y,value Z");
```

Comment: Hash maps do not keep their elements in any guaranteed order, so sorting the keys or values is a common practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If I understand your problem properly, you are trying to see if the inserted values are there in the mapValues array you are getting back. You can use the indexOf function on the array and check something like

```
//start a loop to go through the arrays.
if( mapValues.indexOf("value A") >= 0 )
{
    continue;
}
```

Hope this helps!